# Restheart mongodb filtering by date

Tags: mongodb, rest, date, restheart

I'm currently trying to get some json data from mongoDB database, and I use restHeart plugin for make my query.

I need to filter my answer with all result that the property "_lastupdated_on" is lower than the current date.

I tried something like that but doesn't work :

`http://test:8081/purge/colPurge?filter={'_lastupdated_on':{'$eq':'2016-03-03T14:33:00Z'}}`

Any idea ?

Version mongo 3.2 / restheart 1.1.6

Dorian

Answer (score 0):

The restheart system properties (those starting with _) are not stored in the db and cannot used for filtering and sorting.

You need to put a real date property in the documents to achieve what you need.

A tricky to automatically inject a "last update" field would be using a representation transformer (have a look at this discussion https://github.com/SoftInstigate/restheart/issues/95)