# RestHeart with mongoDB

Tags: json, mongodb, restheart

After asked this question : [topic restHeart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35778707/restheart-mongodb-filtering-by-date) with a satisfactory answer, i have a new question.

I used this http restHeart request :

```
PATCH http://test:8081/purge/test3 { rts: [
{
 "name": "addRequestProperties", 
 "phase": "REQUEST", 
 "scope": "CHILDREN",
 "args": { "log": [ "dateTime", "epochTimeStamp" ] } }]}
```

and now when I insert some json data, mongo db automaticaly add datetime and epochTimeStamp like that :

```
"invoiceNumber": "6666"
"log": {
    "dateTime": "[23/Mar/2016:16:24:24 +0000]"
    "epochTimeStamp": 1458750264
}
```

So my problem is now to make my query.

I tried something like that but does not work :

```
http://test:8081/purge/test3?filter={"log":{"epochTimeStamp":{"$lte":"1458750378"}}}
```

Finally my query retrieve nothing...

Version mongo 3.2 / restheart 1.2

Hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a string to the $lte operator.

You need to pass a number:

```
  http://test:8081/purge/test3?filter={"log.epochTimeStamp":{"$lte": 1458750378}}
```

Comment: Unfortunetly it does not work ! :/. I also try http://test:8081/purge/test3?filter={"log":{"epochTimeStamp":1458811670}}}

Comment: I also try to use your query like that : `http://test:8081/purge/test3?filter={"$and":[{"log":{"epochTimeStamp":{"$gte":1458312597}}},{"log":{"epochTimeStamp":{"$lte":1458812890}}}]}`. Nothing retrieved :(

Comment: I fixed the query in my answer to use the dot notation, can you try it?